# Why will the beam of light diverge in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, refraction

I came across a JEE Mains question, which I found pretty confusing after seeing the actual answer. Here is the question:

> An initially parallel cylindrical beam travels in a medium of refractive index $\mu(I)=\mu_0+\mu_2I$, where $μ_0$ and $μ_2$ are positive constants and $I$ is the intensity of the light beam. The intensity of the beam is decreasing with increasing radius. As the beam enters the medium, it will -
>
> A) travel as a cylindrical beam
>
> B) diverge
>
> C) converge
>
> D) diverge near the axis and converge near the periphery

I imagine the cylindrical beam to be somewhat like this (with less intensity at the edges, and more intensity towards the center:

[image: Cylindrical Beam of Light]

If this beam enters the medium, wouldn't it just travel as a cylindrical beam? The answer says it converges, but I can't seem to figure out how. Could anyone please suggest as to why it converges in this case?

Comment: Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: We have discussed this [in the Problem Solving chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43795723#43795723)

Comment: @JohnRennie I'm sure this is not a homework question. I am studying this chapter for my exams and this question stumped me. This is not a worked example type question either.

Comment: @JohnRennie So should I delete this question now?

Comment: Why the refractive index of the medium is depending on the intensity of radiation? Shouldn't it depend on the frequency?